# jQuery: slide down and replacing one background image with another one in a special manner

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, uislider

Here is a code [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CNt5h/1/).

There are 2 images: new (modern) one and the old one. Everything slides down properly in my example, when you press the link "Click here to slide down" (although I didn't stretch images so they fit each other, that's just an example).

But, I want the new image (modern) didn't slide down, but was smoothly replaced by the old one (by old Google). For example, when the slider is in the middle of the page, there is a half of old Google appeared above that slider and a half of the modern Google disappeared above that slider. At that moment the lower part of the modern image is still below the slider.
As result, if the images contain the same text, fit each other, but have different colors, you can read the whole text from that images at any time of sliding.
I hope I explained it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's what you want.

the background image should stay where it is, so the div is aligned to the page with it's bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/uniisland/9h58G/1/

Comment: Sorry, the green box, the slider should slide down as they do. But, the image should disappear from top - it doesn't move, but disappear from the top border. Please see the explanation in my question. Thank you.

Comment: @Haradzieniec i see. now i get what you meant. wait a minute.

Comment: Wow, looks perfect. Thanks. But, it was tested in FF-perfect, Chrome-perfect, Opera-perfect and IE. IE doesn't work (doesn't slide it down at all). Tested in IE 8.0.

Comment: @Haradzieniec which part doesn't move? or nothing moves?

Comment: @Haradzieniec i'm not sure what's wrong here. the js and css rules are actually quite simple. make sure you understand how it works, and test it on your own site for browser compatibility. since jsfiddle envolves iframes and other complications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if is a solution, but:

I've wrap the body css in a div:

```
<div id="bg"></div>

#bg{
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #d1e3ec;
     background-image: url(http://googlechrometutorial.com/images/google-chrome-home.jpg);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: top center;
     position: absolute;
}
```

and after that we can paly with animation opacity (or other fade ...):

```
 $('#bg').css('opacity', 0);
 $('#slide-link').click(function(){

 var hid = $('#sliderWrapper').is(':hidden')            
 $(this).animate({ top: (1-hid)*($(window).height()) },1500)
      if(hid) {
           $('#bg').animate({'opacity':0}, 1000);
           $('#sliderWrapper').stop().show("slide", { direction:"down" }, 1500);
      } else {
           $('#bg').animate({'opacity':1}, 1000);                                
           $('#sliderWrapper').stop().hide("slide", { direction:"down" }, 1500); 
      }          
 })
```